# How to have a DataTable row and its column have two separate onclick link events

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I have a view with a Datatable. Each row in the table contains different user information in each column including 'First Name' and 'Last Name'. If we click on the 'First Name' or 'Last Name' it should link to the relevant user profile page.

The column links work, however, I also created a link tied to each row in the in the table; if we click the row it should go to a different URL. The event handler code is as follows:

```
 $('#promoters > tbody > tr').live('click', {}, function (e) {
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
             url: "/Ajax/GetUserbyEmail?email=" + $('#email').val(),
       })
    }
```

The issue is that I need both link handlers to work simultaneously. If I click the 'First Name' or 'Last Name' column it needs to link to the profile page and if I click anywhere else in the row then it needs to call the AJAX shown above.

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for many years. If using a version `>=1.7` you should use `on()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ignoring anchors in your click event handler? You can get the event target by `e.target.nodeName`.

[From the jQuery documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$('#promoters > tbody > tr').on('click', function(e) {
    // only execute ajax request when element is not an anchor 'a'
    if( e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "a" )
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Ajax/GetUserbyEmail?email=" + $('#email').val(),
        })
}
```

Comment: think you need to lower case nodeName for IE. Using jQuery `is()` also convenient

Comment: Yes, right. It would be saver then. Thanks. But I don't like to use jQuery in this case. Because you have to cast `e.target` into a jQuery object first, and then use a check with `.is()`. It is slow and not needed in this case, because we don't use the object any further ...

Comment: Hi @eisbehr the solution has worked fine. could you please tell me little about "e", what is this e in the function(e). Much appreciate.

Comment: `e` it the event object, passed from jQuery. It contains some more information about the event. See the jQuery documentation for more info: https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/#the-event-object or https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/